# Unity3D: Reference .cs file in inspector, then get its type at runtime

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, dynamic, reflection

I'm trying to let the user specify their own c# script that inherits from an abstract class I created. I have a working Unity Editor version, but because it is based on MonoScript class which is in the UnityEditor namespace, it gives an error when trying to compile into a built unity executable. I've tried several things but can't seem to get it to work.

If I know the assembly it will be in I can load an assembly and get the class from it by name. But I won't know which assembly the script may reside in, since the User can potentially place it anywhere.

working editor version

```
using UnityEditor; //This is the problem!!
using UnityEngine;

public class test : MonoBehaviour {
    public MonoScript testScript;

    void Start() {
        Type testType = testScript.GetType();
        Debug.Log(testType);
    }
}
```

This version is not dependent on UnityEditor, so it compiles, but it doesn't work.

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class test : MonoBehaviour {

    public TextAsset testScript;

    void Start() {
        Type testType = GetType(testScript);
        Debug.Log(testType);
    }


    Type GetType(TextAsset textAsset) {
        string assetName = textAsset.name;
        Debug.Log(assetName);
        Type type = System.Type.GetType(assetName); //This is null
        Debug.Log(type);
        return type;
    }
}
```

I've also tried a bunch of solutions with getting assemblies and then loading the class by name, but haven't figured out a working solution.

I suspect the answer involves reflection, but I'm a reflection noob.

Comment: You can't do this, not in the way you're trying to anyway. "cs files" don't exist at runtime. They exist as compiled classes.

Comment: I think that's incorrect at least for Unity. If I stick a test .cs file in with name TestCs.cs and then type in `Debug.Log(typeof(TestCs));` it prints out TestCs. The problem is I don't know what the class name is or what assembly it is in

Comment: To be specific, I know the class name, but I can't get its `Type` to use with `Activator` for the above reasons

Comment: unity is precompiled - it wont be reading in cs files. You can load DLL files, containing code, but thats not what you've done here.

Comment: *`Debug.Log(typeof(TestCs)); it prints out TestCs`* Yes, because `TypeCs` (in that context) is a `static` `class` reference. Its like doing `Sometype.class` in Java. But it is *not* a variable of type `Type` and Unity's inspector can't natively serialize `Type` and getting a `Type` knowing only its (string) name involves searching all assemblies to see if it has a `Type` with that name. But even *that* won't let you load an arbitrary text file *as* code.

Comment: @Draco18s Thanks, your comment pointed me in the right direction. I got it working now searching through all assemblies. Will post answer with working solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Draco18s 's comments I got a working solution.

MonoBehaviour with a TextAsset Field.

Drag in C# script. **File Name Must match class name**

This function Gets the type from the text asset name. It relies on below extension method.

```
Type GetType(string typeName) {
   foreach (var assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()) {
       foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes()) {
           if (type.LastPartOfTypeName() == typeName) {
               return type;
           }
       }
   }
   return null;
}
```

With extension method on Type class:

```
public static string LastPartOfTypeName(this Type type) {
    string[] typeNameFull = type.FullName?.Split('.');
    string typeNameLast = typeNameFull?[typeNameFull.Length - 1];
    return typeNameLast;
}
```

Then, create instance:

```
Type savedType = GetType(TextAsset.name);
Activator.CreateInstance(savedType);
```

Comment: `type.FullName` should never be null, so the `?.` operator isn't needed. And even if it was, the result would be null, and then crash when you tried at use the array access.

Answer (score 0):

C# is a compiled language. It is simply not possible to plug in a bit of C# code into a compiled program. You *could* do that with an *interpreted* language, like python or javascript or some custom language made specifically for your game. But, like someone pointed out in the comments, Unity itself, whether you use js in it or C#, produces compiled programs. That's why your Unity editor has to compile code before you can run your game in it (ever noticed that loading indicator in the bottom right corner after you modify your scripts?).

Reflection only allows you to use information about types in a compiled assembly. Think of it this way - compilation is like putting things into a box, and labeling each thing with some data. Once compilation is done, that box is closed. Reflection allows you to access the labels you put with your things into the box, but doesn't allow you to open the box, put something new inside, and close the box again.

To imagine why adding new code into a compiled program is impossible, I think it would help if you realised that this code in C# that you want to plug in could do *literally anything*. There is no way of knowing beforehand whether this code would print a number in console, order pizza or be an entire operating system.

That's why to achieve some degree of what you want, you probably should think about what functionalities you want to expose to your user, and instead of asking for a C# script, ask for some config file, like a json or an xml, and then parse that file in your game. To give you user even more freedom, you could design your own simple scripting language and write an interpreter for it.